Not able to see the endpoint details in the elastic APM, able to see only HTTP verbs
I am using the below otel-config.yaml. I have attached the screenshot in the elastic search APM
I am seeing only the HTTP verb (e.g., GET) but not the full API endpoint in the OpenTelemetry or APM tool, it likely means that the telemetry data is not capturing or displaying the URL path or resource for the API requests.
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"

processors:
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_mib: 2000
  batch:
  metricstransform:
    transforms:
      - include: http.server.duration
        match_type: strict
        action: update
        new_name: http.server.duration.updated
        operations:
          - action: update_label
            new_label: http.method
            label: http.method
          - action: update_label
            new_label: http.route
            label: http.route
          - action: update_label
            new_label: http.status_code
            label: http.status_code

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
  otlp/elastic:
    endpoint: "elastic-cloud.com:443"
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer mjfw"
    tls:
      insecure: false  # Set to true for testing

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]  # metricstransform removed for traces
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [metricstransform, memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [debug, otlp/elastic]



it may be worth trying https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-microservices-distributed-tracing-xray-gradle-java.html#opentelemetry-dependencies to see if that provides a better http.route which should then get captured by the span name which I'm guessing is what the Elastic U/X is displaying there
